# Having problem with retriving json data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm working on a laravel project and i'm getting JSON error. I've try few options to solve the issue but did not come up with any solutions.

In this project I've to send multiple data into database onder one "ID". In that ID there are at list 10 data need to insert. So I used JSON format. It saves ok but getting error when I try to pull data.

Here is my code

Controller :

```
public function newExpenses(Request $request){

        $Jexpenses = new Jexpenses;

        $json = array(
            'des' => $request->description,
            'valu' => $request->expenses
        );

        $Jexpenses->voucher = $request->voucher_no;
        $Jexpenses->date = $request->date;
        $Jexpenses->description = json_encode($json);
        $Jexpenses->expenses = $request->total;
        $Jexpenses->remarks = $request->remark;

        if($Jexpenses->save()){
            $notification = array(
                'message' => 'Expenses Saved',
                'alert-type' => 'success'
            );
        }

        return redirect()->back()->with($notification);
    }
```

result :

```
{"des":["Jon","Sam","Pitter"],"valu":["20","30","15"]}
```

Return Controller:

```
public function expenses(){
        $data = array(
            'title' => 'Expenses',
            'expenses' => Jexpenses::all()
        );

        return view('expenses.expenses')->with($data);
    }
```

html :

```
@foreach ($expenses as $key => $getData)


    {{ $array = @json( $getData->description ) }}


    <tr>
        <td>{{ ++$key }} </td>
        <td>{{ $getData->voucher }} </td>
        <td>{{ $getData->date }} </td>
        @foreach ($array->description as $k => $v)
           <td>{{ $array->des['$k'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $array->valu['$k'] }}</td>
         @endforeach
        <td>{{ $getData->expenses }}</td>
        <td>{{ $getData->remarks }}</td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach
```

it should be work fine but getting error

error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '<' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\acSoft\resources\views\expenses\expenses.blade.php
```

Need some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use `json_decode($getData->description)` instead `@json`. The `@json` is shortly form of `json_encode`

2) `$array->description` not exists property. Should be `$array->des`

3) You use variable in `'` quotes. You should use `"` quote or nothing round variables.

4) It is bad idea using reserved words as variable names. I am about variable `$array`

```
 @foreach ($expenses as $key => $getData)

    {{ $descriptionData = json_decode( $getData->description ) }}

    <tr>
        <td>{{ $key + 1 }} </td>
        <td>{{ $getData->voucher }} </td>
        <td>{{ $getData->date }} </td>
        @foreach ($descriptionData->des as $k => $v)
           <td>{{ $descriptionData->des[$k] }}</td>
           <td>{{ $descriptionData->valu[$k] }}</td>
        @endforeach
        <td>{{ $getData->expenses }}</td>
        <td>{{ $getData->remarks }}</td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: And also  change `<td>{{ ++$key }} </td>` to `<td>{{ $key+1 }} </td>`

Comment: now im getting this 'htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given'

Comment: can you add result of  `var_dump($getData, $descriptionData);`?

Comment: You should not use double braces `{{..}}` when use `var_dump`.  Try do it as that `<?php var_dump(getData); ?>` and remove another lines in `@foreach`